# Disable a button in a radio button group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a radio button group and I would like to dynamically enable/disable buttons.

This is the radio button group code:

```js
$("#option1").prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div style="clear: both; display: inline;">
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="option1label" class="btn btn-info active">
      <input type="radio" class="check" name="options" id="option1" checked>1
    </label>
    <label id="option2label" class="btn btn-info">
      <input type="radio" class="check" name="options" id="option2">2
    </label>
    <label id="option3label" class="btn btn-info">
      <input type="radio" class="check" name="options" id="option3">3
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried all these options below:

```
$("#option1").prop("disabled", true);

$("#option1").attr("disabled", "disabled");

$("#option1label").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

but none of them work. With the last one the buttons look disabled, but you can still click on them and trigger events.

Any ideas appreciated :)

Comment: $("#option1").attr('disabled',true)
$("#option1").attr('disabled','disabled'); are both working for me. What browser / jQuery version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to disable a bootstrap radio button in a group you need to disable the corresponding label and you need to handle click events for the disabled label.

```js
$(function () {
  // for only one radio button
  $("#option1").closest('label').attr("disabled", 'disabled');

  // for all radio
  //$(":radio").closest('label').attr("disabled", 'disabled');


  //
  // On click event check if current label is disabled.
  // If disabled, stop all.
  //
  $('.btn-group label').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is('[disabled]')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
  });

  $('#btnInfo').on('click', function (e) {
    var txt = $(':radio:checked').length == 1 ? 'Checked radio is: ' + $(':radio:checked').attr('id') : 'No radio checked'
    console.log(txt);
  });

  $("input[name='options']").closest('label').click(function (e) {
    console.log('Lbale ' + this.id + ' Clicked!');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div style="clear: both; display: inline;">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label id="option1label" class="btn btn-info active">
            <input type="radio" class="check" name="options" id="option1">1
        </label>
        <label id="option2label" class="btn btn-info">
            <input type="radio" class="check" name="options" id="option2" checked>2
        </label>
        <label id="option3label" class="btn btn-info">
            <input type="radio" class="check" name="options" id="option3">3
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="btnInfo" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show currently checked radio button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I think the problem is with the `attr("disabled", 'disabled')` part of the code, because I tried to insert the `"disabled"` attribute manually into html code `<input>` and also `<label>`, but the button remained clickable and triggered events. Is there any other way to disable the input, without using the `"disabled"` attribute.

Comment: But you see if I add `$("input[name='options']").closest('label').click(function() { alert("Clicked!"); });` to your code snippet, the event gets triggered even when the button has the attribute `"disabled"`. Shouldn't `"disabled"` attribute prevent events such as click to be triggered?

Comment: @patriciasmith Sorry for the delay. I added your click handler in my snippet, and i added a button to the html, swapped the active state from radio 1 to radio 2, because my snippet disables radio 1. Moreover, I added a listener: $('.btn-group label').on('click', function(e) {. When you clik on a label if this is disabled all actions will be stopped. I hope this will help you. Let me know if this is what you was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You jquery selector focuses only first input. Use a selector wich include all the radio of your group, for example:

```js
$(".btn-group input[type='radio']").prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="clear: both; display: inline;">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label id="option1label" class="btn btn-info active">
            <input type="radio" class="check" name="options" id="option1" checked>1
        </label>
        <label id="option2label" class="btn btn-info">
            <input type="radio" class="check" name="options" id="option2">2
        </label>
        <label id="option3label" class="btn btn-info">
            <input type="radio" class="check" name="options" id="option3">3
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the problem isn't with the selector, the problem is that even if I disable the input using `prop("disabled", true)`, the button is still clickable and triggers click events. Even if you manually insert the disabled property in the `<input type="radio" class="check" name="options" id="option1" checked>`, the button still isn't disabled and I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
$('input[name= options]').attr("disabled",true);
```

Comment: Yes, the selector part works fine - the problem is that adding the "disabled" attribute to the <input> or the <label> still doesn't actually disable the button - any suggestions how to disable the button in any other way?

Comment: You need to disable the click event on this button ?

Comment: If you want to disable the click event it's totally different... You have to use `bind / unbind` or `on / off. So could you past your code of your click event please ? What do you have in your click event ?

Comment: But shouldn't the disable attribute automatically prevent all events triggered by mouse clicks?
This is my code for events:
`$("#button-group :input").change(function() {...});`

Comment: The click event isn't on your input but on the label. And if you set disabled property on the label this will disable graphically but the event is always here. But if you disable a real input this will disable the event and graphically. Try my fiddle to understand https://jsfiddle.net/bze5ujom/3/

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!